# How should I structure the test automation code for two different versions of an application

Tags: java, selenium

The web app that I'm writing automated tests for (selenium + java) has two versions. Depending on the version there are different locators and also some layout differences like a pop-up in one version of the application and the lack of it in the other. Basically making another class with different locators won't suffice as there will be some new methods as well.

I'm thinking what the best approach to structure the code would be. Namely, should I create one abstract class and then extend it with two classes, one for each version of the app ? Or maybe make some if/else/switch statements in the methods where different implementation is needed ? What is the general approach in such cases ?

Answer (score 0):

Managing different branches for same functionality leads to maintenance overhead in longer run. Prefer handling the situations conditionaly.